# LXDE crashes randomly

Tags: raspbian-stretch, pi-3b+, lxde, lxsession

I've been using this Pi for a while now, and only recently this problem begins to happen:

I'm doing some programming (Geany, lxterminal, pcmanfm are running) and then suddenly the icons in lxpanel disappear and are replaced by invalid icons, and when I try to click on anything in lxpanel, I get "Invalid desktop entry file: /usr/share/raspi-ui-overrides/whatever_Program_I_Clicked.desktop"

Additionally, when I try to run a command in the open lxterminal (bash) I get **"Input/output error".**

**System:** Raspberry Pi 3b+

**OS:** Raspbian GNU Linux 9.9 (stretch)

Comment: The reason I'm not using Buster is because when I upgraded to it, my Pi wouldn't boot from my external SSD, and wouldn't even give me the rainbow screen.

Comment: It is not recommended to upgrade Stretch to Buster. Either re-flash your existing sd card or flash a new sd card with Buster using Etcher.

Comment: Understood, but currently my Pi is running Stretch, not Buster, and it's not the one which failed the upgrade. Perhaps I should file a LXDE bug? Where would I find information applicable to Input/Output error?

Comment: If you file a bug - the first thing they will ask is are you using the very latest software - which is Raspbian Buster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After two days, and a lot of work troubleshooting, I've fixed the problem by:

a) Inserting my problematic disk into another computer

b) Unmounting the directory (it was automatically mounted) by `umount /dev/sda1`

c) Running `sudo fsck /dev/sda1`

It turned out to be a bad bit, and now the problem is all fixed. For future reference, the problem *wasn't LXDE,* **the problem was a corrupted SSD.**